# Is there anyway to maintain document hierarchy when querying cosmos db for nested values without full projection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Imagine a cosmos document like this:

```
{
  my_field: 1,
  my_object: {
    my_inner_field: 2
  }
}
```

If you query like so:

```sql
select my_field, my_object.my_inner_field
```

The projection effectively flattens the behind the scenes structure to this result:

```
{
  my_field: 1,
  my_inner_field: 2
}
```

This can be 'fixed' (assuming you want the nesting still) by explicitly delcaring the projection as:

```sql
select my_field, { my_inner_field: my_object.my_inner_field } as my_object
```

However for a large nested object this gets more an more unmanagable. Ideally there would be some way of flagging/asking cosmos to restrict the fields but not to fully project/flatten the hierarchy

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish by doing that, but... I don't see how this could work differently. And nope, there's no option like that.

Comment: @DavidMakogon essentially if you have a large complicated document schema that you want as the output schema (in terms of nesting) but with optional fields e.g. sparse fieldsets style.  I'd like a neat way of effectively filtering to specific values within the document schema (as opposed to projecting to an entirely new thing) rather than having to project and 'repeat' the entire schema within the document.  The key problem really here is using a projection mechanism (select) where I want _easy/terse_ field filtering instead.